# Javascript navigate to visualforce page button

Tags: visualforce, javascript, button, navigation

I basically need to mimic the button content source: Visual Force Page logic
[image]

I can't use the Visual force drop down button because I need to check that a field is filled in first. So I need to use the javascript option instead, but still need to navigate to a visual force page. I also can't make that field mandatory before saving.

Code:

```
var id = '{!Case.Paradigm_ID__c}';
if(id.length == 0){
     alert("No Paradigm ID, SSRS History will not be linked");
}
else{

     window.location = //link to visual force page here
}
```

Comment: Can you be a little more clear what you're trying to do? You just want the user to be able to click a button to take them to a page, but only if a field is filled out? You can still use a VF element and combine it with JS..

Comment: What vf element? This is within the custom buttons and actions setup area. It's exactly the same thing that the 'Content Source: VisualForce Page' does just with a preliminary step.

Comment: Oh, I thought this was on a VF page, you didn't say anything about being the definition of a custom button haha. I see it now. Anyway, what exactly is the trouble you're having with this? You're trying to reference a field on Case in the JavaScript of a custom button?

Comment: How would I navigate to the custom visualforce page? The vf page uses a case as a standard controller, and the vf page uses the case's fields. So when navigating to it, it would have to know case that it navigated from.

Comment: You misunderstand me, I just mistakenly thought you were talking about this in the context of a page, I'm not saying you should do that haha. One solution would be to do a SOQL query in the JS based on the id from the URL. There is probably a more elegant or "recommended" solution but it would work.

Comment: Oh, I thought you were asking how to validate the input from just a button, not the URL for a VF page...looks like you got it anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
window.location.href='/apex/VFPageName'
```